# Assignment compatibility of function: why can '(v: number) => any' be assigned to '(v?: number) => any'?

Tags: typescript

I wonder why the following code can pass the type-checking.

TypeScript 3.2.1

```
const f: (v?: number) => string = (v: number) => v.toString();
f(void 0); // Compiled Successfully, but cause Run-time Error
```

I expect the assignment lead to compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your compiler setting. To get an error in this case you need to enable `strictFunctionTypes` and `strictNullChecks`